# I need some direction on a Web API - MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How do I return all values in a List from the Details View page?  I am currently only getting the first Value in the "ItemLines" List - which is the Description Field.  I need to show all of the "ItemLines" in a dynamic table in the details page.  Help is appreciated!

```
My Details.cshtml page:
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CitationNumber)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CitationNumber)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CaseStatus)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CaseStatus)
    </dd>
  **I want loop through the ItemLines List and display Description, BilledAmount, PaidAmount**
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemLines)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemLines);
    </dd>
```

Here is my Model

```
namespace CPA.Models
{
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
public class AlertMessage
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; }
}

public class ItemLine
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int BilledAmount { get; set; }
    public int PaidAmount { get; set; }
}

public class CitationDetail
{
    public string CitationNumber { get; set; }
    public string DefendantName { get; set; }
    public string DateofBirth { get; set; }
    public string VehicleTagNumber { get; set; }
    public string CaseType { get; set; }
    public string CaseStatus { get; set; }
    public string AppearanceDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsPayable { get; set; }
    public int FineSuspended { get; set; }
    public int FineServed { get; set; }
    public List<AlertMessage> AlertMessages { get; set; }
    public List<ItemLine> ItemLines { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<CitationDetail> CitationDetails { get; set; }
    public int CitationCount { get; set; }
    public bool SuccessfulSearch { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@model  CitationDetail

......  // your code
.......

@if (Model!=null && Model.ItemLines!=null)
{
  @for(var i=0; i <  Model.ItemLines.Count; i+=1)
  {

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemLines[i].Description)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemLines[i].Description);
    </dd>

       .... and so on for   BilledAmount, PaidAmount
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - I tried the code and have the error below.

Comment: Error CS0019 Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'List<ItemLine>' 3_Views_Citation_Details.cshtml

Comment: @Tdigges Sorry for a typo , it should be  i <  Model.ItemLines.Count;

Comment: Awesome! Works now!